HOW to access emacs after installing using snap
After installing emacs with snap with the command: sudo snap install emacs --classic, the terminal result was:
emacs 29.3 from Alex Murray (alexmurray✪) installed
Then , when I tried to open emacs using emacs command and checked version using emacs --version, both time i got the following error:
bash: /usr/bin/emacs: No such file or directory
So, how to solve this so that I can successfully install emacs using snap??

Make sure that /snap/bin is in your $PATH
You can add the following line to your .bashrc or .zshrc:
export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin

